# Is it possible to trigger a function upon some Vue data elements change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to watch for a batch of data elements and when they will be changed, store them into localStorage.

Is there any convenient way to do this?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you have tried?

Comment: **watchers** are exactly for that: to watch changes. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) for this.

```js
<script>
    const SomeComponent = {
        name: 'SomeComponent',
        data() {
            someData: null,
        },
        watch: {
            'someData': {
                handler(newValue, oldValue) { // sets off when `someData` changes
                    this.someMethod();
                },
                immediate: true, // if you also want to execute the handler above on creation of the component
            },
        },
        methods: {
            someMethod() {
                // do something with this.someData
            }
        }
</script>
```

Sadly, you have to add a watcher for every data element that you want to watch, even if you want to execute the same function. If you want to avoid this you can create an object in your data, put your data inside this object and watch this object. You then need to pass `deep: true` at the watcher (like we did with `immediate` in the example above). This will watch for all changes on the object and trigger the method accordingly.